# Still getting SettingWithCopyWarning after using iloc. Where does it come from?

Tags: python, pandas

I am getting a the SettingWithCopyWarning message.

> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py:670:
> SettingWithCopyWarning:  A value is trying to be set on a copy of a
> slice from a DataFrame
>
> See the caveats in the documentation:
> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy
> iloc._setitem_with_indexer(indexer, value)

I have been trying to figure it out for hours but cannot spot where the issue is. Can anyone shed a bit of light?

This is the code:

```
df = pd.read_excel(path).assign(rate = np.NaN, alert = np.NaN)

def incidence(data, treshold):

  #iterates through each row of dataset 
  for i, row in enumerate(df.itertuples()):
    try:
      #divides total_rdtpost by total_rdtused
      data.rate.iloc[i] = row[5]/row[7]
    except ZeroDivisionError:
      #fixes the ZeroDivisionError, please read https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html#ZeroDivisionError 
      data.rate.iloc[i] = 0.0
    #creates a low or high record depending on the treshold variable
    if data.rate.iloc[i] > treshold:
      data.alert.iloc[i] = "high"
    else:
      data.alert.iloc[i] = "low"

  return data

incidence(df, 0.2)
```

PS. I am using Colab.

Comment: maybe df.itertuples() should be data.itertuples() ???

Answer (score 0):

`data.rate` and `data.alert` is short for `data['rate']` and `data['alert']`, respectively. `data['rate']` *can* be copy so doing `data['rate'].iloc[i]` is still a copy.

Change those to be like:

```
data.iloc[i, data.columns.get_loc('rate')] = ...
```

And you can save the column indexes beforehand:

```py
def incidence(data, treshold):
    # at the start of the function
    rate_col = data.columns.get_loc('rate')
    alert_col = data.columns.get_loc('alert')
    ...
    for ...
        # later
        data.iloc[i, rate_col] = ...
```

Btw, your for-loop references the global/outer `df` and not the `data` passed in to the function. It should be:

```
for i, row in enumerate(data.itertuples()):
```

---

Another thing, you may as well do all the steps in the function as column operations instead of using `itertuples`. You're modifying the dataframe in the function anyway.